# How to get the username of the current user and assign it to a certain field in a form in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

This is my models.py file

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.



class Book(models.Model):
    category_choices =(
        #("Undefined","Undefined"),
        ("Action", "Action"),
        ("Romance", "Romance"),
        ("Horror", "Horror"),
        ("Comedy", "Comedy"),
        ("Adventure", "Adventure"),
        ("Dramatic", "Dramatic"),
        ("Crime","Crime"),
        ("Fantasy","Fantasy"),
    )
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    author = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to= 'photos/%y/%m/%d', blank = True)
    category = models.CharField(
        max_length = 20,
        choices = category_choices,
        #default = 'Undefined'
        )
    publication_year = models.CharField(max_length=4, null=True)
    ISBN = models.CharField(max_length=13, null=True, unique=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default= True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Borrow(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    book = models.OneToOneField(Book, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    period = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book)
```

and this is my forms.py file

```
from django import forms
from .models import Borrow


class BorrowForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Borrow
        fields = ('name', 'book', 'period')
```

and this is the function in my views.py file that renders the form

```
@login_required
def borrowing(request):
    momo = BorrowForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        momo = BorrowForm(request.POST)
        if momo.is_valid():
            instacne = momo.save(commit=False)
            instacne.user = request.user.username
            instacne.save()
            return redirect('profile')
    return render(request, 'books/book.html', {'momo': momo})
```

The role of this function is to render that form and to save the data that user will enter and automatically assign the username of  the current user to the field 'name' in form.

I tried alot of things to get the username of the current user and assign it to the field 'name' but nothing works and that field stays blank.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You're using a `models.ForeignKey(User)` so that table will store a user id, not a username. I'd call this field `user` and not `name`, personally.

Therefore you need to provide a user instance to it like this;

```
@login_required
def borrowing(request):
    initial = {}
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        initial.update({'name': request.user})
    momo = BorrowForm(initial=initial)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        momo = BorrowForm(request.POST)
        if momo.is_valid():
            instance = momo.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = request.user
            instance.save()
```

If you wanted to easily get the username for a `Borrow` instance you could do this;

```
class Borrow(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    book = models.OneToOneField(Book, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    period = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.book)

    @property
    def username(self):
        return self.name.username
```

If you want the form to offer users by username, you can either have the `str` method of your user model return username, or create custom choices as a tuple of user ID & username in the form `__init__`

Comment: is there any way to add parameter `instance = ` in `BorrowForm()`

like that:  `momo = BorrowForm(instance = request.user.username)`

Comment: @AhmedHalim You want to do something with the instance in the form?

Comment: yes, because as you see at the image above 
there's a field `Name` that contains a list of the usernames of all users who have signed up before, so it must be unallowable for user to borrow a book using another username of another user, so we can't keep it visible for users. I'm just showing it to explain that it is really blank 
so I need that form to instance the username of the current user automatically

Comment: @AhmedHalim Ok, it sounds like you want to provide an initial value to the `name` field of the current user, so I've updated the view to show how to load initial data.

Comment: Wow thank you it worked. But what should i do if I want to make the field name a non editable field so that the user can not change it.

Comment: Probably make it a hidden input @AhmedHalim